# How to add cxml doctype using XSLT

Tags: xslt, doctype, cxml

I am generating correct cxml but doctype is missing in the beginning.

How can I add the below doc type after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and copy the remaining xml using XSLT mapping.

```
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.032/cXML.dtd">
```

Desired output should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.032/cXML.dtd">
<xml>
<field>.... (followed by remaining xml structure)
```

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:output method="xml"
  doctype-system="http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.032/cXML.dtd"
/>
```